# Flutter app - Notification settings option

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications, settings

How do I create the notifications settings page in a flutter app? There is no official documentation regarding this.

Most mobile apps have a settings page where users can enable/disable specific types of notifications. **How to integrate various notification options in Android and iOS settings?** I am using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Here are some Notification settings samples:

[image]

---

OS level notifications settings:

[image]

Comment: Any info on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 1):

the best solution i have it's when user click the button
i  take him to notification setting for the device

U can use a package for that like " open-settings"